# Why slash is removed after domain?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, options

I have installed different sites through my admin panel as below screenshot.

[image]

But when I click any of the menus of My Sites it is redirected to the wrong URL like,

- `https://www.example.comwp-admin/netowrd` instead of `https://www.example.com/wp-admin/netowrd`
- `https://www.example.comwp-admin/netowrd/sites.php` instead of `https://www.example.com/wp-admin/netowrd/sites.php`

> Problem is happening only with this menu.

Means slash is removed automatically after domain or before wp-admin.

Why this is happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this issue as well and realised I had:

```
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '' );
```

in one of my configs and it should've been:

```
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: WordPress multisite requires that some additional [PHP constants](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/#step-4-enabling-the-network) are set. In my case someone had incorrectly removed the slash from the PATH_CURRENT_SITE constant.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, check the values of the options in `wp_options`. I haven't used multisite in a while, but you should make sure that the `siteurl` and `home` options have slashes on the end of the URL and see if that fixes it.